# MySQL: Auto increment with even or odd numbers only?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to have auto increment field which generates even or odd numbers (skips the opposite)? The reason I am asking is because I want to share auto increment between two tables. Other ways for achieving it are welcomed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How exactly do you plan to share the autoincrement field between the two tables? It might be relevant to the answer.

Comment: Simply said - the two tables are identical (work with both) and I have to avoid number repeating of their auto increment fields.

Comment: Can You describe task with more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can offset one table's auto increment field from the other, i.e. one table starts ids from 1 while the other starts from 1000000 (or some other value chosen depending on your usage pattern).

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT);
CREATE TABLE table2 (id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT) AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000000;
```

You can also choose your autoincrement column type according to your needs. BIGINT UNSIGNED's range is 0..18446744073709551615, which should cover most cases.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by Juergen you could do that at system level instead of session level by making following change (or adding) in my.ini file:

```
auto-increment-increment = 2
auto-increment-offset = 1
```

or

```
auto-increment-increment = 2
auto-increment-offset = 2
```

Basically this is much used in Master-Master replication setup.

Comment: Yes, but taking in count it will have global effect won't really suit me.

Comment: alright then in that case you should go with the session based approach which will last no longer than your connection from the php script.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=2;
SET @@auto_increment_offset=2;
```

Comment: Where are you supposed to write that?

Comment: Anywhere you want. Execute it where you would run queries to the server - for instance with mysql workbench.

Comment: Hmm, maybe planetscale's MySql just doesn't support it (they don't support foreign keys either so it wouldn't be too suprising). https://i.gyazo.com/bc15ab76f698a7824efdff2fbdf45969.png

Answer (score 2):

You can use triggers to achieve custom autoincrement functionality.

Create table to store custom autoincrement values and insert one row with initial values:

```
CREATE TABLE autoincrement_id (id_even INT, id_odd INT);
INSERT INTO autoincrement_id VALUES (0, 1);
```

Create triggers, that will modify inserted row's id value accordingly:

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_id_in_sometable_with_odd_id BEFORE INSERT ON `sometable_with_odd_id`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET NEW.id = (SELECT id_odd FROM autoincrement_id LIMIT 1);
   UPDATE autoincrement_id SET id_odd = id_odd + 2;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER set_id_in_sometable_with_even_id BEFORE INSERT ON `sometable_with_even_id`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET NEW.id = (SELECT id_even FROM autoincrement_id LIMIT 1);
   UPDATE autoincrement_id SET id_even = id_even + 2;
END;
```