# Put unique index across more than one table

Tags: mysql

I have run into a problem where the easiest solution would be to add a unique index that goes across multiple tables in mysql. Is this possible?

For the purpose of this question I will have three tables; `status`, `tracks` and `events`. The `status` and `tracks` tables both have an auto incrementing ID (`T_ID` or `S_ID`) in. Information from them is added to the `events` table with a trigger. The problem is that there could be the same auto incrementing ID in `tracks` and `status`, this means that their could be the same ID more than once in `events`.

`tracks`;

```
CREATE TABLE `tracks` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`url` varchar(200) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`T_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`T_ID`),
UNIQUE KEY `url` (`url`),
UNIQUE KEY `T_ID` (`T_ID`),
KEY `ID` (`ID`),
CONSTRAINT `tracks_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `members` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci
```

`status`

```
CREATE TABLE `status` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`status` varchar(300) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`S_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`S_ID`),
UNIQUE KEY `S_ID` (`S_ID`),
KEY `ID` (`ID`),
CONSTRAINT `status_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `artists` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci
```

`events`

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`action` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`E_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
KEY `ID` (`ID`),
CONSTRAINT `events_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `members` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci COMMENT='This table shows what the artist has done and is used feed'
```

Comment: Spanning one index across multiple tables is not possible I'm afraid.

Comment: @BenGriffiths Ah thats no good. Any ideas on what I could do instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed, you cannot have an index across multiple tables.

However, consider changing your schema by adding a "source" column to your event table and making a unique constraint on the combination of the source and the foreign key. This would prevent duplicate keys being inserted from the same source.

Comment: I'm not worried about dupicate entries from the same source as that can't happen. I am worried about duplicate entries from different sources

Comment: I think you are risking integrity by writting keys from separate tables to the same field without specifying the source. However, there is another way to achieve what you are trying to do. You can set the auto increment offset on each of the tables, track and status. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776437/mysql-auto-increment-with-even-or-odd-numbers-only

Comment: You can easily identify the source from the `action` column. The action that is inserted depends on what triggers it, so it can be `has uploaded a track` or `has some news`. Thanks I shall have a look, i didn't think of doing it that way.